# Index of values in array returned by if-statement Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement

I have an array:

```
arr = [["group1", "user1", "user2", "user3", "AD-user1", "AD-user2"],
       ["group2", "user4"]]
```

I want to do something like that:

```
arr.each do |item|
        if (item.include? "AD-user") then
            arr_h = { "Group" => arr[1],
                      "User" => arr[number_of_element_with_AD-user_name] }
        else
        #something else
        end
end
```

and I have no idea how to define index of values found in if statement. In this case I have two user names starting with "AD-user" string, but it can be a lot of them. Name of group is always the first value in subarrays.

Comment: what about [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) ?

Comment: Ok, but how to use it in this case?

Comment: What is the expected output? What if there are multiple items in the array, that include `'AD-user'`? Does `each` really make sense in this context, when you assign one variable (`arr_h`), that might be overridden in the next iteration?

Comment: Expected output is the index of found value. If there are multiple items in the array I want to put all new hashes to an array doing arr_new << arr_h

Comment: @mila002 how would `arr_new` look like for the given example array?

Comment: When item contains of AD-user string I want new array look like arr_new = [{"Group" => "group1", "User" => "AD-user1"}, {"Group" => "group1", "User" => "AD-user2"}]. When doesn't contain AD-user I need to run some commands on every other user so I need if-statement in this part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_ary = []
arr.each do |a|
  b = a.select{|e| e.include? "AD-user"}
  if b.empty? 
    #something else
    new_ary << {"Group" => a[0], "Users" => "AD-user not available"}
  else
    new_ary << {"Group" => a[0], "Users" => b}
  end
end

> new_ary
#=> [{"Group"=>"group1", "Users"=>["AD-user1", "AD-user2"]}, {"Group"=>"group2", "Users"=>"AD-user not available"}]
```

---

```
new_ary = []
arr.each do |a|
  b = a.select{|e| e.include? "AD-user"}
  new_ary << {"Group" => a[0], "Users" => b}
end

> new_ary
#=> [{"Group"=>"group1", "Users"=>["AD-user1", "AD-user2"]}, {"Group"=>"group2", "Users"=>[]}]
```